# Is there a way to write a pointcut for a getter to an annotated field?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I'm trying to write a pointcut which will intercept getters for annotated members.

```
public class MyClass {

    private String volume;

    @MyAttribute
    private Validity validity;


    public void setValidity( Validity obj ){
        validity = obj;
    }

    public Validity getValidity(){
        return validity;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to write a pointcut that will intercept all calls to `getValidity()` based on `validity` being annotated with `@MyAttribute`?  Written differently, I'm looking to create a pointcut for any getter of a member field that is annotated with `@MyAttribute`.

A simple getter pointcut can advise any getter method:

```
pointcut embeddedGetter() : execution( public * com.ia.domain..get*());
```

but that won't specify that the field it is getting has to be annotated.  And if I put a modifier in front of `public` that would specify that the getter method has to be annotated, which isn't the case.

Is this even feasible?

Comment: There should be an `@annotation` pointcut designator and you can probably use a wildcard expression for the name of the method (and its return type).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis but if I am creating my pointcut on getters how do I relate that to the annotation on the field?  Any annotation matching will be based on the getter's annotations - not the field.

Comment: Oh, I missed that part. I thought the getter was annotated. I don't think you can associate a method with a field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After playing around with AspectJ, I finally rediscovered the join point I was looking for:

```
pointcut embeddedGetter() : get( @MyAnnotation Validity *..* );
```

The key is not to use the `execution` pointcut but rather the `get`.

Comment: Do you happen to know the Spring AOP equivalent of this pointcut? I have been trying to find it for some time now with no luck.

Comment: @PranjalGore I haven't used spring aop in quite some time, but the last I recall it was unable to creat these pointcuts.  It was limited to public executable methods.  Consequently, it would be and to creat a pointcut to the getter directly but not by the field.